# Optimizing SQL request

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, request

Im using PDO Mysql, and made a request to select cheapest offers for a product in my database. It works fine, only problem is it is slow (for 200 offers (and still just 25 to return)) it takes almost a second, which is a lot higher than what I aim.

I'm no expert in SQL, so I seek for your help on this matter. Here is the request and I'll be happy to provide more info if needed :

```
SELECT
            mo.id AS id, 
            mo.stock AS stock, 
            mo.price AS price,
            mo.promotional_price AS promotional_price, 
            mo.picture_1 AS picture_1, 
            mo.picture_2 AS picture_2, 
            mo.picture_3 AS picture_3, 
            mo.picture_4 AS picture_4, 
            mo.picture_5 AS picture_5, 
            mo.title AS title, 
            mo.description AS description, 
            mo.state AS state, 
            mo.is_new AS is_new, 
            mo.is_original AS is_original, 
            c.name AS name, 
            u.id AS user_id, 
            u.username AS username, 
            u.postal_code AS postal_code,
            p.name AS country_name, 
            ra.cache_rating_avg AS cache_rating_avg, 
            ra.cache_rating_nb AS cache_rating_nb, 
            GROUP_CONCAT(md.delivery_mode_id SEPARATOR ', ') AS delivery_mode_ids, 
            GROUP_CONCAT(ri.title SEPARATOR ', ') AS delivery_mode_titles

        FROM 
            mp_offer mo, catalog_product_i18n c,
            ref_country_i18n p, mp_offer_delivery_mode md,
            ref_delivery_mode r, 
            ref_delivery_mode_i18n ri, user u 

        LEFT JOIN mp_user_review_rating_i18n ra 
            ON u.id = ra.user_id 

        WHERE (mo.product_id = c.id 
                AND mo.culture = c.culture 
                AND mo.user_id = u.id 
                AND u.country_id = p.id 
                AND mo.id = md.offer_id
                AND md.delivery_mode_id = ri.id 
                AND mo.culture = ri.culture) 
            AND (mo.culture = 1
                AND p.culture = 1) 
            AND mo.is_deleted = 0
            AND mo.product_id = 60 
            AND ((u.holiday_start IS NULL)
                OR (u.holiday_start = '0000-00-00') 
                OR (u.holiday_end IS NULL)
                OR (u.holiday_end = '0000-00-00') 
                OR (u.holiday_start > '2012-05-03')
                OR (u.holiday_end < '2012-05-03')) 
            AND mo.stock > 0
        GROUP BY mo.id 
        ORDER BY IF (mo.promotional_price IS NULL,
                    mo.price,
                    LEAST(mo.price, mo.promotional_price)) ASC 

        LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0;
```

I take the offers for a particular product that have their "culture" set to 1, are not deleted, that have some stock and whose seller is not in holidays. I order by price (promotional_price when there is one).

Is LEAST a slow function?

Here is the output of EXPLAIN :

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys                                                                       key     key_len ref                                 rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      c       const   PRIMARY,catalog_product_i18n_product,catalog_product_i18n_culture                   PRIMARY 8       const,const                         1       "Using temporary; Using filesort"
1   SIMPLE      mo      ref     PRIMARY,culture,is_deleted,product_id,user_id                                       culture 4       const                               3       "Using where with pushed condition"
1   SIMPLE      u       eq_ref  PRIMARY,user_country                                                                PRIMARY 4       database.mo.user_id                 1       "Using where with pushed condition"
1   SIMPLE      p       eq_ref  PRIMARY,ref_country_i18n_culture                                                    PRIMARY 8       database.u.country_id,const         1   
1   SIMPLE      r       ALL     NULL                                                                                NULL    NULL    NULL                                3       "Using join buffer"
1   SIMPLE      ra      ALL     NULL                                                                                NULL    NULL    NULL                                4   
1   SIMPLE      md      ref     PRIMARY,fk_offer_has_delivery_mode_delivery_mode1,fk_offer_has_delivery_mode_offer1 PRIMARY 4       database.mo.id                      2   
1   SIMPLE      ri      eq_ref  PRIMARY                                                                             PRIMARY 2       database.md.delivery_mode_id,const  1
```

Thanks in advance for your help on optimizing this request.

J

Comment: At first - show explain and your schema

Comment: Start with adding index to the JOIN ids (if not already set to PRIMARY).

Comment: It is already set to PRIMARY indeed. I edited my question with the output of explain

Answer (score 0):

You are not making use of ref_delivery_mode table that you have included in from clause. It's getting cause of Cartesian product of tables result.

Comment: Cant find reference to the table in the rest of the query either. Well spotted.

Comment: Yes I noticed that a few seconds before your reply. I was using it, but i'm not anymore. Removing that line made me gain something like 150ms on the request. It's a good start, too bad I haven't more useless lines !

Comment: remove the order by clause from sql, because it will force to fetch all record and then apply order by and display only 25 records.

Comment: First store the result in a temp then apply order by clause there. It will be very fast as compare to your solution.